# Как правильно делать полноэкранную секцию на сайте

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Как сделать шапку сайта так, чтобы она была на весь размер окна, но при этом не меняла своего размера. Объясню, в хроме на андроид когда скроллишь вылезает панелька с урл и кнопкой настроек, она изменяет размер вьюпорта, поэтому банальное `height: 100vh; width: 100vh;` не подходит, т.к. страница скачет, есть вариант сделать ресайз через js, при событиях `scroll resize` и только когда данная секция видна во вьюпорте. Какие вообще есть техники для таких хитростей?

Comment: Еще подобная проблема есть в safari на iPhon, в зависимости от версии iOs в safari присутствуют либо только верхняя панелька, либо и верхняя и нижняя. Причем, они накладываются на вьюпорт, не изменяя его размер, отследить их не представляется возможным, но на iphone4 в горизонтальной ориентации они скрывают почти треть экрана, на iphone5 около четверти. Для супер-пупер верстки приходится писать стили для каждого такого устройства.

Comment: А шапка должна скролится?

Comment: @OlmerDale Не обязательно

Answer (score 0):

В общем я написал свой собственный скрипт. [jsResizer](https://github.com/xahon/jsresizer)
Ресайзит секцию под размер экрана, только если секция видна во вьюпорте